# Pin "How do I write a good answer?" in the Help Center

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center

While giving feedback on first answers, I often find it convenient to also link to [*How do I write a good answer?*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the Help Center. Since I haven't thought about a good "template" text I can copy and paste (yet), I often find myself looking up that link in the Help Center myself.

As you can see in the screenshot below, the link is not visible directly, but is left to be found under `» View more`.

[image: Screenshot of the corresponding Answering section in the Help Center]

Would it be possible to pin that link similar to *What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?*?

IMHO, the *Asking* section does a way better job to present useful links directly.

Comment: As a mod on other SE site, and after looking many other SE sites' help center, and [reading this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187570/241919), looks like all have the same pinned articles, and mods can't unpin/pin other articles.

Comment: I would consider this topic as a definite *read first*. But I see your point in that other SE sites have the same Help Center structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just pinned that network-wide. Though, here in particular, since the article is an override of the network-wide one, I had to pin it manually too... which means I'll need to go check where else it's overriden, and pin it there too :P

**Update:** Turns out it's only overriden here and in some of the international SO's (Russian, Japanese, and Spanish), and the Russian Language site.